# .htaccess RewriteRule Conflict Error

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have htaccess file problem. I think my htaccess files conflict.

my .htaccess files:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)/video/ video.php?vid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)\.html search.php?q=$1 [L]

RewriteRule sitemap-(.*).xml sitemap.php?sayfa=$1 [L]
```

and my url

Search : `http://www.domain.com/search/search_query.html`
Video Play : `http://www.domain.com/path1/video/video_name.html`

.htaccess file conflict video.php and search.php

pls help me

Comment: Please explain the problem

Comment: my search query post video.php and search.php.. but i want post only search.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change order of your rules to keep specific ones first and generic ones later:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^search/(.*)\.html$ search.php?q=$1 [L]

RewriteRule sitemap-(.*).xml$ sitemap.php?sayfa=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/video/ video.php?vid=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: searching working now
example : http://www.domain.com/search/video-name.html

but video.php 404 error


Not Found

The requested URL /JSOBsc1RTaU/video/Shakira---Cant-Remember-to-Forget-You-ft-Rihanna-Official-Video-Captions-Lyrics-On-Screen.html was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

example : http://www.domain.com/videoid/video/video-name.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using a negative lookahead to prevent the two rules from getting applied to each other:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(?!search)(.*)/video/ video.php?vid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^search/(?!video)(.*)\.html search.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Comment: thanks for help me but this .htaccess

Not Found

The requested URL /search/kylie.htm was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.